# List available updates for dependencies listed in project.clj

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I'm using lein to manage my project, and I have a number of `:dependencies` as well as `:dev-dependencies`. Is there a way to find out if there are updates available for these dependencies?

Comment: Is there a solution for this that works with leiningen 2.5?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't tried it myself, but there is Licenser's lein-search plugin, which has:

> lein update (updates all artifacts in your deps, asking for each one if you'd like it)

It's at http://github.com/Licenser/lein-search.

Comment: Thanks Matthew. The one you linked to didn't work out of the box with Clojure 1.2-RC1, but I found a more up to date version [here](http://github.com/luskwater/lein-search) which worked great.

Comment: Since seeing this answer, I've been hacking on lein-search too: you can check out my fork here: http://github.com/purcell/lein-search (clojars: org.clojars.sanityinc/lein-search 0.3.0-SNAPSHOT)

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to using the Leiningen plugin, which is a good bet, you can always search the default Leiningen repository, [Clojars](http://clojars.org/).

Answer (score 0):

I can also recommend `lein-ancient`, available [here](https://clojars.org/lein-ancient) on clojars. 
(Some of the other answers are rather old.)